# How can I use the result of the function as parameter for the same function?

Tags: python, function, recursion

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

number_of_cards = int(input())
indexes = [3,3,2]

deck = [i for i in range(1, number_of_cards + 1)]

def func(lst, index):
    shuffle1 = lst[:index]
    shuffle2 = lst[index:]
    res = []
    for val in list(chain(*zip_longest(shuffle1,shuffle2))):
        if val != None:
            res.append(val)
    return res

a = func(deck, 0)
b = func(a,1)
c = func(b,2)
d = func(c,3)
print(d)
```

I would like the use the same function but not hardcoded as I made it.
Basically I want to mimic the last 5 rows in a new function.
Please Help

Comment: You don't need recursion for that. `result = deck` and `for i in range(4): result = func(result, i)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop:

```
for i in range(4):
    deck = func(deck, i)
```